# Finding the second derivative by differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given $x^5y + x +y^3 =3$, I have found the first derivative to be

$x^5\, \frac{dy}{dx} + 5x^4y+1+3y^2 \, \frac{dy }{dx}= 0$.

Need help calculating the second derivative.

Comment: just do the same thing again

Comment: I need help with doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use:** $\frac{d}{dx}uv=u\frac{dv}{dx}+v\frac{du}{dx}$

$x^5\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+5x^4\frac{dy}{dx}+5x^4\frac{dy}{dx}+20x^3y+3y^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+6y(\frac{dy}{dx})^2=0$ and simplify.

Comment: I think you did a mistake in the last term

Comment: yes you are right . thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use $uv$ rule for differentiation. 
$$ \frac{d}{dx}(uv) = u\frac{dv}{dx} + v\frac{du}{dx}$$.

For example $\frac{d}{dx}(y^3\frac{dy}{dx}) = 3y^2(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 + y^3\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$